# How do I check if any part of String B is in String A

Tags: java, regex, string

I am currently programming a music bot that gets music from Spotify. I am struggling to check if both the song name and the artist is contained in the users query(needed because Spotify looks for album names before song names, so it looks for the most popular song in an album that fits the users query)

This is what my code is currently:

```
String query="Megadeth Holy Wars";
String artist="Megadeth";
String songName="Holy Wars...The Punishment Due - 2004 Digital Remaster";

System.out.println("Query >>> "+query.toLowerCase());
System.out.println("Artist >>> "+artist.toLowerCase());
System.out.println("Song name >>> "+songName.toLowerCase());
System.out.println("Query contains artist: "+query.toLowerCase().contains(artist.toLowerCase()));
System.out.println("Query contains song name: "+query.toLowerCase().contains(songName.toLowerCase()));
```

This is the output:

```
Query >>> megadeth holy wars
Artist >>> megadeth
Song name >>> holy wars...the punishment due - 2004 digital remaster
Query contains artist: true
Query contains song name: false
```

Currently I use a split but I dont think that that is a good way to handle it so I would like to know if there is a good way that both of the statements are true.

Comment: You are going to need to use some type of loop or recursive function to test if parts of the songName are in query. I personally think you should use two different queries if possible. One for the artist and one for the song name.

Comment: this is the result i would expect, as the song title is actually not contained in the query, that would need more thinking about how to do it, and probably not simple, in lots of cases, it's the query's song title that will be a substring to the real song title. But you can't search if query is contained in the song title, because there is the artist too in it.. not simple (+1 for the song example, good one)

Comment: Once you have found the artist, try to remove it from the query and check if the rest of the query contains the song name. (You might run into trouble with the song Motörhead from Motörhead on the album Motörhead though)

Comment: @StephaneM replaceFirst can solve that

Comment: StringUtils.indexOfAny(query, songName.split(" ")); would be pretty slow, I'm guessing

Answer (score 0):

I am convinced that you will have to use two searches. One for the artist and one for the song name - as Sedrick suggested - otherwise this will be very difficult with a convoluted query.

- The first step is to identify the artist. Because there are many more overlapping and duplicate song titles. (There are also overlapping and duplicate artist names but less often in absolute numbers compared to song titles.). Some AI or machine learning could greatly improve the accuracy to get the right artist.
- Then you can try to subtract the artist name from the query and search for the song title with the remainder. (Ideally, just within the list of song titles that belong to the identified artist retrieved by some sort of select query.)

I hope this helps!